# IE thinks jpeg is bmp

Tags: php, internet-explorer, symfony1, gd, jpeg

I have a image thumbnail function that basically just re-sizes the image and outputs it via GD

It shows fine on all browsers, except in IE where it thinks it's a bmp file... which is fine usually except when I'm trying to use jquery to drag it and the file takes ~10s to render everytime I drag it... not sure why...

When I try to save the image file, it will default to Untitled.bmp and not let me change the file type.

I even tried to load the image file directly by copying it from the cache, and it works fine, so the file itself is ok... but I just can't get symfony to output the image in a way ie 'likes'...

things I have tried so far:

- Content-Type: image/jpeg
- Content-Type: image/pjpeg
- Content-Type: application/download + Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.jpg"
- Content-Type: image/jpeg + Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.jpg"
- Content-Type: image/jpeg + Content-Disposition: inline:filename="test.jpg"
- Content-Type: application/download + Content-Disposition: inline;filename="test.jpg"

I have added Content-Length to all of the above and it goes fine through on firebug's net panel... but ie's developer tools > image report says the filesize is -1 bytes.

The only thing left that I can think of is the url of the image:

`http://www.example.com/imagePreview?component[0][id]=1&component[0][option_id]=5&component[1][id]=2&component[1][option_id]=4&width=400`

I tried to add a `.jpg` at the end, but it still refuses to read the file as a jpeg...

So yea, I need some ideas and help from you guys

Comment: Have you had a look inside the file to determine the file type?

Comment: it's a jpeg file for sure, as I copied the cached file and loaded it with IE and it loads it as a jpeg properly (saves as jpeg when i tried to save it)

Comment: Which version of IE does it apply to?

Comment: I tested IE 7 (with IE8) and 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I fixed the laggy issue with dragging the image:

After animating opacity to 100%, the alpha filter remains there even after the animation has finished, even though the filter does absolutely nothing it still has to process which was what was causing the huge lag.

Solution to drag lag:
- After animation unset css opacity: $(this).css('opacity', '')

As for the jpeg being interpretted as bmp, I guess it wasn't the cause of the drag lag, and at the end of the day it doesn't matter <_<

Answer (score 1):

Please remember that the IE cache is just that: [a cache](http://jeffcode.blogspot.com/2008/05/tif-really-is-cache-and-it-acts-like.html). If an image [isn't in the cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffdav/archive/2003/12/08/53607.aspx), the only representation IE has is the in-memory representation that GDI uses, which is a BMP.

Comment: I outputted the GD image into a jpeg, then used readfile to read the jpeg file. The cached jpeg file also loads properly in IE as a jpeg, not bmp, but using readfile via php/symfony causes IE to refuse to 'believe' it's a jpeg

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove the Temporary Internet Files. Old IE versions had an annoying bug: when cache got full, images were saved as BMP.

Comment: Seen this solution as well, but it didn't work. I have cleared the cache everytime I tried a new Content-Type or Content-Disposition combination